# Socket programming in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I wanna implement a chat application. When i gone through few threads and tutorials, i think i need to use socket programming for this purpose. Can anyone provide some basic idea for socket programming in iphone.And what all things i have to refer for famliarizing with socket programming.

Thanks and regards,
Sreelash

Answer (score 2):

I think the [AsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) might make things easier for you, would save you from having to use the Core Foundation stuff directly.

Comment: What about the CFNetwork framework. Whats this AsyncSocket. Can you just brief about it?

Comment: Sure. I haven't used AsynSocket myself, but basically, it's a wrapper for all of that CF (Core Foundation) networking stuff. This allows you to work in Objective-C as with the rest of your code, instead of mixing your code with the pretty confusing C language Core Foundation stuff directly. In other words, the functionality of what you would normally use directly (CFNetwork, CFSocket, etc.) is wrapped in Objective-C.

Comment: Hi Blaenk,

I have found a documentation for AsyncSocket(http://homepage.mac.com/d_j_v/.Public/AsyncSocket4.3/AsyncSocket%20Documentation.html). In this doc, they have only specified the delegate methods for using AsyncSocket. It would be better if i got some working samples of AsyncSocket. Do you have any?

Regards,
Sreelash

Comment: There are some example projects in the trunk directory of the subversion repository for the project. They include sample implementations and code for the delegates: http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/source/browse/#svn/trunk

Comment: Links mentioned over here are not available now

Answer (score 0):

try this click [here](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) 
you can get how to send and receive message using socket programming. you have to use node.js at server side..