# best way to start learning socket programming in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets

i am a beginner in `objective c` and `iphone` and i have undertaken a project of 'client

server program' . but i m not having any idea about `sockets` in iphone . can  anyone plz 
suggest me some books or links from where i can easily understand the `sockets` and their

programming in objective c. i recently studied [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Listings/AppController_m.html) but didn't find it helpful

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple doc's are best to learn any concept related to iOS.
[Setting Up Socket Streams](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI), [Networking and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2277/_index.html)

Check the below link,

[Example socket programming in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524843/example-socket-programming-in-iphone)

[Socket programming in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581469/socket-programming-in-iphone)

Answer (score 4):

First start with Socket Programmming in C. [read](http://www.slideshare.net/jignesh/socket-programming-tutorial) this  presentation for start,it will help u.